# charge transection fee from user flutterwave ravepay?

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

I am using [flutterwave](https://flutterwave.com/us/) for the first time and I heard that there is an option to charge the transaction fee on the user while processing the payment but I am not sure how to do it. I am searching it a lot on their docs and on other sources but I didn't find anything useful regarding this [flutterwave documentation](https://developer.flutterwave.com/docs/getting-started) This is the official documentation which I am referring throw but I did not fount anything related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable this in your dashboard settings.

- Login to your account
- Click on settings on the bottom left of the screen (You might need to scroll down if you are on a small screen)
- Click on Account Settings
- Select your preferred option on the `Who should pay the transaction fees?`
   item.

[image]

Comment: ya I found this but when I switched to make the customer pay the transaction fees it does not show any fee amount at transaction page and when I logged into the portal and see the receivable amount in  transection it deducted from my side I am not sure why this is not working.